# Calculate rolling shutter or shutter speed based on video footage?

Tags: shutter

I have [made a video](https://youtu.be/A77ft4eGXhA) where i pan evenly across vertical surface (white door edge) and i can notice rolling shutter happening, how do i calculate exactly the amount of rolling shutter or camera shutter speed based on this video footage?

So far i can tell whole movement from edge to edge of the sensor took 1second video made at 50fps so about 1000ms/50ms = 20ms movement speed between frames.

But how do i get shutter speed out of this?